# What are the current best options for parallelizing a CPU-intensive .NET app?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing

This is an open-ended question.  What approaches should I consider?

Comment: What hardware?  If it is CPU intensive, and you only have 1 single-core CPU, then multiple threads will decrease performance.  Also, if you need to parallelize to a cluster of PCs, that is a very different animal than multiple threads on 1 PC.

Answer (score 10):

Your first step is to find and understand the parallelism in your problem. It is really easy to write multi-threaded code that performs no better than the single-threaded code it replaces. "Patterns for Parallel Programming" [(Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321228111) is a great introduction to the key concepts.

Once you have a workable design, start reading the articles in the "Concurrency" topic in the MSDN Magazine archives [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc159269.aspx), particularly anything written by Jeff Richter. Those will give you the nuts and bolts stuff on the threading constructs specific to Windows and .NET. (The multi-threading section in Richter's "CLR via C# [(Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632)is short, but very insightful - highly recommended.)

Answer (score 6):

There are some parallel extensions to .NET that are currently in testing and available at Microsoft's [Parallel Computing Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/default.aspx). They have a few interesting items that you would expect like Parallel foreach and a parallel version of LINQ called PLINQ. Some of the best information about the extensions is on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/Parallel+Extensions/).

Answer (score 2):

I think we could also include non-.NET-specific approaches to parallel processing if those are among the best options to consider.

Answer (score 2):

@Larsenal

If you want to branch outside of .NET there has been a lot of discussion about Intel's [Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) which is a parallel library for C++.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options and the best solution will depend on the nature of the problem you are trying to solve.  If you are trying to solve an [embarassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem then dividing and parallelising the tasks will be trivial.  In that case the challenge will come in distributing and managing the data used.

Some suggestions would be:

- [ICE Grid](http://www.zeroc.com/icegrid/index.html) which has bindings for .Net and other common languages
- [Velocity](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B24C3708-EEFF-4055-A867-19B5851E7CD2&displaylang=en) which is Microsoft's version of Oracle (Tangersol) Coherence
- The forthcoming HPC offering from Microsoft [Compute Cluster Server](http://www.microsoft.com/HPC/)
- [Data Synapse Grid Server](http://www.datasynapse.com/)